# Is h↓ the correct IPA representation of the ingressive "fast gasp", meaning "uh-huh", in French?

Tags: phonetics, ipa, french

Spoken French has *two* ingressive forms of "yes". One is "ouais" [wɛ↓], equivalent to "yep" in English. The other is a "pure" ingressive sound, described sometimes as a "[fast gasp](https://www.ouiinfrance.com/the-strange-noises-french-people-make/)", and is equivalent to "Yeah, uh-huh" in English. Would [h↓] be the most correct way to represent this in IPA?

Edit: Corrected symbol order as per comment.

Edit 2: Added external reference to description of "fast gasp".

Comment: It looks like the `↓` IPA symbol is to be put after the ingressive sound, not before it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingressive_sound

Comment: Yup, that sounds like [hꜜ] to me, now that there’s an audio recording included.

Comment: Janus, how about editing this and some of your other comments into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you want them to be "ingressive"?
I would describe the second yes as [n̩̊] a voiceless syllabic nasal.
It seems that the IPA does not provide diacritics for that kind of sounds which are pronounced without opening the mouth.
French also has [m̩̊] to mean "looks good (to eat)".

Comment: [n̥] does require opening the mouth. If your mouth is closed, it’s at most an [n̥͡m̥], but probably just an [m̥]. I would also dispute that a voiceless egressive nasal is what’s at play here at all. As isolated sounds, [n̥] and [m̥] are virtually indistinguishable; they require a voiced element to be distinguishable. The sound typically used to mean ‘yummy’ is a syllabic, voiced [m̩ː] – it would be quite bizarre if French used a voiceless nasal, which sounds like trying to blow out a candle with your nose rather than like yummy food.

Comment: Also, the _ouais_ described in the question definitely is ingressive, conforming quite nicely to the typologically common concept of words meaning ‘yes’ or ‘no’ having possible ingressive variants frequently used in casual speech. English _yeah_ and _yup_ have such ingressive variants as well, though they’re not common in all dialects. A simple intake of air [hꜜ] is equally common as a sign of agreement or encouragement, and I don’t see why this shouldn’t be the case for French also.

Comment: Both [n̥̍] and [m̥̍] are voiceless, because they are pronounced without any vibration. Besides, they are pronounced with the mouth shut, as I wrote before. And they are not ingressive as a rule. (@ J.B Jacquet) your comments are a priori theory (would, should, etc).

Comment: Can you link to a recording of these sounds? I am by no means a native French speaker, but I have never heard either of the sounds you describe, whereas I _have_ heard the ingressive _ouais_.

Comment: As regards [m̥̍] see here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdbfZExK7R0&t=14 she speaks a mixture of French and (?) Arabic, but anyway her [m̥̍] with mouth shut is representative.

Comment: I don’t hear any unvoiced [m̩̊]’s in that clip at all. If you’re talking about the very beginning when she says, “Mmm, c’est très délicieuse…”, that is very audibly a fully voiced [m̩ːː], not an unvoiced one. There is plenty of vibration here – if there weren’t, you wouldn’t be able to hear her voice at all as she says it. If you close your mouth and blow air out of your nose (like when blowing your nose when you have a cold), _that_ is an unvoiced [m̩̊]. This video has some examples with sound: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=CcSsEbwyBFk (sadly none syllabic, only as /m̥a ~ am̥/).

Comment: Another case of [n̥̍] is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErnZEnWsFmI&t=34

Comment: That too is fully voiced. An unvoiced [n̩̊] is what you get in many languages (certainly English, I think French too) when you scoff derisively at someone, often transcribed ‘hmph’ or similarly. Sometimes there’s voicing in the latter part of that sound, but it starts off voiceless (so it’s [n̥͡n] or something like that). The encouraging ‘mmm’ or ‘nnn’ in the _Cage aux folles_ clip, conversely, is completely voiced throughout.

Comment: I can’t find anyone talking specifically about ingressive [hꜜ] in French, but I did find a video about a guy talking about ingressive _ouais_ (“_ouais_ inspiré” as he calls it) as a pet peeve – you can hear very clearly there what sound the question is talking about: https://youtu.be/YVwbxp1FyiE.

Comment: Yes, but *ouais* does not need nor must be ingressive. It can be so, quite rarely, and it's not compulsory. That was my initial point.

Comment: Of course it doesn’t _need_ to be – that wasn’t what the question meant to imply either, I’m sure. But an ingressive variant does exist, and (though I don’t recall hearing it), I don’t doubt that the other ingressive marker of encouragement/agreement mentioned is also used at least by some French speakers.

Comment: I have analyzed [n] in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErnZEnWsFmI&t=34 with Praat. It's indeed more voiced than what I thought, but it's not voiced throughout. Part of it is unvoiced, about 30% at the end. So it's [nnn̥͡]. Besides, the first [n] is distinctly recognizable even over short lapses of time (like 0,1 s). The second [n] is more complex and less recognizable when heard over short lapses of time.